# How to scrape the confirmation sign in Python on EarningsWhispers?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

On EarningsWhispers, I would like to scrape (in Python) the '(confirmation) sign' of the earnings date.

[Screenshot of the confirmation sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A58bv.png)

This is the code I am currently having :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
URL = "https://earningswhispers.com/stocks/aph/"
html_code = urlopen(URL).read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code)
divTag = soup.find_all("section", {"id": "mainbox"})
```

With this output:

```
 [<section class="tickerlookup" id="mainbox">
 <div class="icon-stock3" id="mainicon"></div>
 <h1 id="maintitle">Ticker Lookup</h1>
 </section>]
```

But afterwards, I think I need to refer to the **datebox** and the title **We last confirmed ..**:

```
<div id="datebox" class="topbox"><div class="boxhead">Wednesday</div><div 
id="epsconfirmed" class="ewtip icon-checkmark color-yes" title="We last confirmed the 
release date with the company on Monday, January 10, 2022"></div><div 
class="mainitem" onclick="location.href='/calendar?d=10&amp;t=all'">Jan 26</div><div 
id="earningstime">8:00 AM ET</div><a id="ical" class="icon-addcalendar ewtip" 
href="webcal://beta.earningswhispers.com/jsdata/ical.aspx?symbol=APH" title="add to 
your calendar"></a></div>
```

Link:
https://earningswhispers.com/stocks/aph

Can someone help me out ?
I think I am really close to the solution.

Thanks,
Mathias

Answer (score 0):

If you use selenium or similar module, you can get the html after javascript runs.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
ser = Service("chromedriver.exe")
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=chrome_options)

url =  'https://earningswhispers.com/stocks/aph'
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Then using this:

```
soup.find(attrs={'id':'epsconfirmed'})
```

you get

```
<div class="ewtip icon-checkmark color-yes" id="epsconfirmed" title="We last confirmed the release date with the company on Monday, January 10, 2022"></div>
```